# Verifying the minimum cost from each node to a sink node in linear time

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal, weighted-graph

**Problem Statement:**

Let *G = (V,E)* be a directed graph with costs *c<sub>e</sub>* ∈ ℝ on each edge *e* ∈ *E*. There are no negative cycles in *G*. Suppose there is a sink node *t* ∈ *V*, and for each node *v* ∈ *V*, there is a label *d<sub>v</sub>* ∈ ℝ.

Give an algorithm that decides, in linear time, whether it is true that for each *v* ∈ *V*, *d<sub>v</sub>* is the cost of the minimum-cost path from *v* to the sink node *t*.

**Attempt:**

The biggest challenge I find is the linear time limitation. The most relevant algorithm to consider here is the Bellman-Ford algorithm, but runs in O(|V|·|E|) time which is too slow, so it requires modifying for this problem.

I have also made an observation:

If, for example, *(u,v)* ∈ *E*
and *c<sub>(u,v)</sub>* = 1, and *d<sub>u</sub>* = 3 and *d<sub>v</sub>* = 5, then the label *d<sub>v</sub>* is wrong. This is because passing from *v* to *u* with a cost of 1 and travelling from *u* to *t* in a minimum cost of 3 for a total cost of 4 is shorter than the supposed minimum cost from *v* to *t* given by *d<sub>v</sub>*, which is 5.

I'm not sure if I can use this insight to produce a linear algorithm, but it's the furthest I have gotten so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your insight is an ingredient to an efficient algorithm. Given a node *u* — different from *t* —, its outgoing edges *e=(u,v)* should fulfill this condition:

*c<sub>e</sub> + v<sub>d</sub> ≥ u<sub>d</sub>*

In addition to this, at least one of those edges *e* should be in the node's minimum cost path:

*c<sub>e</sub> + v<sub>d</sub> = u<sub>d</sub>*

The above two conditions can be condensed into the following, where *E<sub>u</sub>* is the collection of edges that originate in *u*:

*min(c<sub>e</sub> + v<sub>d</sub>) = u<sub>d</sub> for e=(u,v) ∈ E<sub>u</sub>*

Finally, the minimum cost path at the sink *t* should be zero:

*d<sub>t</sub> = 0*

So, it is possible to design an algorithm that visits all nodes and their outgoing edges exactly once in order to verify these conditions.

#### Time Complexity

If you have the graph represented with an adjacency list, then this can indeed be done in *O(|V| + |E|)* time. If the graph is connected, then this boils down to *O(|E|)*.

#### Pseudo Code

```py
function verify(nodes, sink):
    if sink.label != 0:
        return False
    for node in nodes:
        if node != sink:
            cost = infinity
            for e in node.outgoingEdges:
                cost = min(cost, e.target.label + e.cost) 
            if node.label != cost:
                return False
    return True
```

For an implementation in Python, see [this repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/VerifyMinimumCostPath)